# How can I input data into csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have a project in that I want to input data into csv.

I want the data to be saved in the first column if the data is smaller than 500 and another datum can be saved in the second column if the value is bigger than 500.

```
import csv
def rawInputTest():
    x = raw_input(">>> Input: ")
    print x
    return x

def writeToFile(xx):
    with open('WorkOrderLog.csv', 'a') as f:
         w=csv.writer(f)
         a=0
         b=0
         if xx>500:
             b=xx
         elif xx<500:
             a=xx
         g=[a,b]
         w.writerow(g)
while (True):
    rawInputTest()
    writeToFile(rawInputTest())
```

The result I expect is like that:

> input: 600
>
> input: 300

The result should be `[300,600]`.

If you retype again, then the data should be saved into the second row.

Comment: You're on the right track. Because you're getting each input value one at a time, the simplest approach would be to collect two values before you write them to the file. But there are other considerations to think about, too. For example, what happens if the user inputs two values that are greater than 500?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you compare strings that `raw_input` returns with integers. In Python 3 that would raise a `TypeError` whereas Python 2 just happily continues to work with the incorrect input.

You can convert the input into an int in a `try:...except ValueError:` block, before you pass it to the `writeToFile` function.

Since you want two inputs, you have to call `raw_input` twice and then pass the values to the write function. I'd write the program similar to this solution:

```
import csv


def writeToFile(writer, x, y):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    if x > 500:
        b = x
        a = y
    elif x < 500:
        a = x
        b = y
    g = [a, b]
    writer.writerow(g)


with open('temp.csv', 'ab') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    while True:
        x = raw_input('>>> Input: ')
        y = raw_input('>>> Input: ')
        try:
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
        except ValueError:
            print 'Invalid input: {}, {}'.format(x, y)
        else:  # No error.
            writeToFile(writer, x, y)
```